# remove full stop from end of word in golang

Tags: go

I am new to golang. I need to remove full stop from end of word but not from floating point. I looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734443/regex-python-remove-full-stop-from-end-of-word-but-not-in-float). The python approach `r'(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)'` is not exactly applicable in golang so following this [cheatsheet](http://yourbasic.org/golang/regexp-cheat-sheet/), I wrote below

```
re, err := regexp.Compile("[.$]")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

processedString = re.ReplaceAllString("3.2isgood.", "")
```

But that doesn't work. Can you please suggest?

Comment: You put it in square brackets, indicating a character class, but that doesn't seem like what you actually want.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work". Neither of these looks like what you're describing, which would simply be `\.$`

Comment: Yup, just as @JimB mentioned [example](https://regexr.com/3nltg). I would like to add that it might be better to use `Trim` instead of regex here, for performance sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably not use regex here, how about strings.Trim here instead?
(caveat- would not go through and find any in the middle of the words.)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    testCases := []string{
        "abc.",
        "123.45",
        "How about in the middle. Is that ok?",
    }

    for _, tc := range testCases {
        fmt.Println(strings.TrimSuffix(tc, "."))
    }
}
```

Output:

> abc
>
> 123.45
>
> How about in the middle. Is that ok?

Comment: strings.TrimSuffix would remove it from the end and _not_ the start, if that's your desired behavior.